# Problem Installing Ubuntu 18.04.3: Installation Freezes at “Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service”

Tags: system-installation

I am a first time Linux user installing via USB per Ubuntu instructions, I have booted into Linux OK, Ubuntu loaded straight to what I’m guessing is the default desktop.

Upon clicking the Install Ubuntu icon at the top left, the circular *wait* cursor animation begins and after several minutes a terminal like screen displays with:

```
Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

A few minutes later, some `system-shutdown[1]` logs are printed off.

I am attempting to install on Lenovo ThinkPad p72.

Comment: Did you verify the ISO after download?  https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and then your write to your install media? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck

Comment: My download verified OK, but I can't seem to find a way to verify the installed media (USB versus CD/DVD) just yet, continuing to search forums.... thank you for your reply.

Comment: Your install media (be it cd, dvd, usb-thumb-drive, hdd, ssd or whatever you used) is referred to as CD (or 'disc') for validation.   You use the 'Check disc for defects' option, which requires a key-press for the menu to appear for some machine's BIOS, or the menu automatically appears (your BIOS/UEFI setup controls if a key-press is required for the menu to appear).  If you see keyboard-in-rectangle & person-in-circle you press a key & menu appears for example.

Comment: Pressing a key while booting from USB brought me to GNU Grub v2.02 instead of the desktop, any idea why? I was not sure how to attempt verifying the install that way as I am not well versed in bash commands yet.

Comment: What you describe to me implies you need to validate your media!  If you look at the second link I provided; it's a menu option you highlight with arrow keys & then press ENTER. It's "Check CD for defects" in the link I provided, where you'll see "Check disc for defects".  If you're having problems running it on that box; I'd try another box (the ease of the menu appearing is controlled by BIOS/UEFI settings which is why I'm suggesting different box). If you can't get it to appear on two different boxes - I'd blame a bad-write & re-write to your media.

Comment: Will definitely try on a different machine, as I still have not been able to enter the menu when booting from USB. Pressing a key while doing so loads GNU Grub, not pressing a key loads the default desktop wherein I encounter the same problem. Thank you for your help, I will let you know what happens on a different machine /different UEFI.